# How to give notification to user to update their app

Tags: android

I have created an app which I publish in the android market. After a few days, I added new features in my app and again publish these new features app in the android market. Now my question is how can notify a user that is using my older version app to update it to a new version. Is there something I have to write in the code or something I have to change in the android market.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do nothing, Android Market does this check for new versions and updating.
However, users may choose not to be notified about app updates.

Comment: Thats what is not showing update notification in my device..Actually i publish my older version of app last week..Tommorrow i added some features and publish the newer version of the app in android market...but till now no notification appears in my device.so why these happen...as i know these thing are automatically handle by android market..